# Header unresponsive

Tags: html, css

I have a header but when resizing the screen, the elements on it start to hide themselves as the screen gets smaller, I haven't been able to fix it and I'm wondering if anyone might know how to fix this.
Here's my html:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="left">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="bars"></i>
                <h1 class="logo">Notebook</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="text" class='searchbar' placeholder='Search Notes'>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="bell-wrapper">
                    <p class="notifications">8</p>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-bell"></i>
                </div>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar" id="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-items">
            <p>Home</p>
            <p>Lists</p>
            <p>Editor</p>
            <p>Settings</p>
            </div>
            <div class="logout-login options"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="section">
                <button class="create-note">Create Note</button>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <div class="list-of-notes">
                    <div class="intro-message add-note-message welcome-note">
                        <p>Don't have any notes yet? <a href="">Add one here</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p class="copyright">- All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my styles.css:

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap:2px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:300px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:70px 500px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "sidebar content"
    "footer footer";
    overflow:hidden;
}

.header {
    grid-area:header;
    border-radius:2px;
    display:flex;
    border-bottom:1px solid #efefef;
}

.sidebar {
    grid-area:sidebar;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:#ffffff;
    border-right:1px solid #ebebeb;
    transition:width 0.4s;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    position:relative;
    /*left:-300px;*/
    transition:left 0.4s;
}

.content {
    grid-area:content;
    border-radius:2px;
    position:relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
    grid-area:footer;
    border-radius:2px;
    background: #efefef;
    border-top: 1px solid #d6d3d3;
}

.header .left {
    width:150px;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}

.left .fa-bars {
    color:#01000a;
    padding:12px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:2px;
    margin:10px;
}

.left .fa-bars:hover {
    background:#efefef;
}

#bars {
    display:none;
}

.left h1.logo {
    font-family:"Inter", sans-serif;
    font-weight:500;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:25px;
    color: rgb(1, 0, 3);
    margin:20px;
}

.header .center {
    flex:1;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;

    justify-content: center;
}

.center input.searchbar {
    border: 1px solid #f7f2f2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 16px;
    /*width: 900px;*/
    width:100%;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 12px 2px #fffcfc;
}

.center input.searchbar::placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto',"Poppins", sans-serif;
    color:rgb(228, 220, 220);
    font-size: 16px;
}

.content .section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    /*background: #efefef;*/
    margin: 1px;
}

.section .create-note {
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    padding:16px;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:#efefef;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family:"Roboto",sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    margin:10px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 12px 2px #fffbfb;
    width:200px;
}

.section .create-note:hover {
    background:#5558f5;
    color:#fff;
}

.section .list-of-notes {
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left:10px;
    position:relative;
}

.list-of-notes .intro-message > p {
    font-family:"Roboto",sans-serif;
}

.list-of-notes .intro-message a {
    font-family:"Roboto",sans-serif;
    color: rgb(124, 100, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header .right {
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:flex-end;
}

.right .bell-wrapper {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border-radius:2px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    position:relative;
}

.bell-wrapper .notifications {
    position:absolute;
    top:-5px;
    right:-5px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    border-radius:50%;
    font-family:"Roboto",sans-serif;
    padding:2px;
    font-size:14px;
    background:#5558f5;
    color:#fff;
}

.right i {
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#01000a;
}

.right i:hover {
    background:#efefef;
}

.sidebar .navbar-items {
    width:100%;
    height:60%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.navbar-items p {
    font-family:"Roboto",sans-serif;
    color:#01000a;
    padding:15px;
    border-radius:2px;
    margin:12px;
    text-align:center;
}

.sidebar .options {
    width:100%;
    height:40%;
}

.footer p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 15px;
    color: #01000a;
}
```

Heres my responsive.css, where I tried to make the header responsive:

```
@media screen and (max-width:818px) {
    .center {
        max-width:530px;
    }

    .center input.searchbar {
        max-width:450px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:618px) {
    .left .logo {
        display:none;
    }

    .content {
        display:none;
    }

    .footer {
        display:none;
    }

    #bars {
        display:block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:599px) {
    .sidebar {
        left:-300px;
    }

    .left {
        max-width:60px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:414px) {
    /*.center input.searchbar {
        max-width:200px;
    }*/

}
```

When resizing the screen, you'll notice the header is responsive but at like less than 750px, it begins to hide the bell and settings icon, I'm trying to fix that part.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? PHP runs on the server when the page is composed, it can't do anything responsive.

Comment: It's a php file, I just haven't added serverside stuff yet @Barmar.

Comment: That's irrelevant. Once it gets to the client, the serverside language doesn't matter. You do responsive design with CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: I know, I did..

Comment: I'm trying to see what's wrong with the css that's causing my header to not respond to all screen sizes.

Comment: You almost never want something like this, to start with: `.container {overflow:hidden;}`.

Answer (score 1):

I made some adjustments in your media queries:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 818px) {
    .center {
        max-width: 530px;
    }

    .center input.searchbar {
        max-width: 450px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 618px) {
    .left .logo {
        display: none;
    }

    .right {
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .footer {
        display: none;
    }

    #bars {
        display: block;
    }

    .header {
        justify-content: space-between; 
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    .sidebar {
        left: -300px;
    }

    .left {
        max-width: 60px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
    /*.center input.searchbar {
        max-width:200px;
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.